# Is it possible to use array elements in shell scripting as revision arguments in svn log?

Tags: arrays, shell, svn, unix, scripting

I have two arrays. Array1 has list of start dates and Array2 has list of end dates.

How should I iterate through this array elements so that I use svn log as :

svn log -r array1[0]:array2[0] url

First of all I want to know is it possible to use array elements in svn log.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 arrays pre-populated with date values, then you can do something like below:

Considering both arrays are of equal length & you want see logs in specific date range-

```
len=${#arr1[*]}

for (( i=0; i<len; i++ ))
do
  to=${arr1[$i]}
  from=${arr2[$i]}
  svn log -r "{$from}:{$to}" <url>
done
```